# Appcelerator PICKER with only day and month

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

is it possible to set a picker with only month and day ?
I could not find this information into the documentation.

Comment: Kindly provide the documentation you are referring to

Comment: I am looking at the documentation at http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Picker

Comment: I faced a similar situation and had to create a native picker module for android as the android custom picker looks somewhat like iOS. The Ti.UI.Picker needs to be manually populated with the month and day data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not create your own custom picker for date and month,

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
exitOnClose: true,
backgroundColor:'#FFF',
});
var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
borderRadius:5,
backgroundColor:'#3f33fe',
width:100,
height:150
});
win.add(view);

var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
top:0,
height: '80%',
useSpinner: true
});
picker.selectionIndicator = true;

var column1 = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();

for(i=1; i<13; i++){
var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title: i

});
column1.addRow(row);
}

var column2 = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();

for(j=1; j<32; j++){
var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({ title: j });
column2.addRow(row);
}

picker.add([column1,column2]);

view.add(picker);

win.open();
picker.setSelectedRow(0, 0, false); 
picker.setSelectedRow(1, 0, false);
```

Comment: Yep, this is the way to go since the default date picker includes day as well.

Comment: I did the picker myself, it was a perfect solution, many thanks, also with it I could specify the rows according to the language, seemed better than set a default UI element.

Comment: @RicardoGimenesFerreira how did you handle edge cases for month dates?... Can you share your code.